# Tableofcontents: Remove pagenumbering from TOC (not first page)

Tags: table-of-contents

I would like to create a `\tableofcontents` (no modifications) but without page numbering. So here this is very minimal-MWE:

```
\documentclass[13pt,a4paper,headlines=6,headinclude=true]{scrartcl}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\newpage
\section{Topic A}
\section{Topic B}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you going to use `hyperref`?

Comment: I think I can do without hyperref. What solution is there?

Comment: Forget my statement about `hyperref`. It works too with `hyperref`, see my solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the `KOMA` classes do not provide other means, the easiest way is to patch the `\thepage` in `\addcontentsline` out.

This is the definition of `\addcontentsline` in `latex.ltx`:

```
\def\addcontentsline#1#2#3{%
  \addtocontents{#1}{\protect\contentsline{#2}{#3}{\thepage}}}
```

By applying a patch to kick the `\thepage` out, there will be an empty `{}` pair then, i.e. no page number.

```
\documentclass[13pt,a4paper,headlines=6,headinclude=true]{scrartcl}


\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchcmd{\addcontentsline}{%
  {\thepage}%
}{{}}{\typeout{success}}{}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\section{Topic A}
\section{Topic B}

\end{document}
```

[image]